# How to add field in existing table phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I'm a newbie in phoenix. I created a simple `api` in my phoenix project the problem is that i want to add another field in my `todo.ex`

I want to add an author field in my todo.ex

**FROM**

```elixir
defmodule TodoApi.Todo do
  use TodoApi.Web, :model

  schema "todos" do
    field :description, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:description])
    |> validate_required([:description])
  end
end
```

**TO**

```elixir
defmodule TodoApi.Todo do
  use TodoApi.Web, :model

  schema "todos" do
    field :description, :string
    field :author, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:description, :author])
    |> validate_required([:description, :author])
  end
end
```

**But I'm getting an postgrex error 42703 column t0.author does not exist**

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to add a migration for todos table.

If you use ecto, just generate a migration using `mix ecto.gen.migration todos_add_author_column` and add a column in the newly generated `priv/repo/migrations/<timestamp>_todos_add_author_column.exs` file like this :

```
def change do
  alter table("todos") do
    add :author, :text
  end
end
```

[Here's a link to docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#alter/2)

Comment: So i need to create another file for this ?? then execute ecto.migrate ?

Comment: You can execute mix task `mix ecto.gen.migration todos_add_author_column`. It will generate the migration file for you. You will just need to populate its `change` function

Comment: Thanks i've successfully gen and migrated the author field the problem now is i can't seem to add data using postman its only adding the description not the author.

Comment: @Priz, is your `TodoApi.Todo` module exactly the same as in the question?

Comment: Yes its exactly the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164065/discussion-between-inomnicausa-and-priz).